# Diagnostics configuration for Azure Deployment throws an error

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-diagnostics

I'm trying to get diagnostics to work on my Azure Web Worker Role.  I start out with the stock Web Worker Role solution by selecting 'New Project/Azure Cloud Service'.  If I de-select the 'Enable Diagnostics' on the properties Worker Role, then I can successfully deploy the stock web role.  It doesn't do much, but it deploys and appears to run.  If I select the 'Enable Diagnostics', the deploy fails with:

```
9:27:34 PM - Applying Diagnostics extension.
9:27:37 PM - Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: s
```

I've tried various combinations for the 'Configure...' choices but get the same error.  This appears on two machines now, so the chances that it's some sort of corruption are slim.

Anyone have a clue what's going on or have a simple, working example of emitting and reading diagnostic messages?

Comment: What version of the SDK are you running?

Comment: Latest SDK, same error here, no changes locally, looks like this is Azure side..

Comment: Did you upgrade the SDK?

Comment: Same problem here. Worked yesterday at 8AM UTC, did not at 10PM UTC. Intalled nothing, did not reboot the computer and did not even close Visual Studio. And no project files updated, no settings changed. Make me think the problem is external. Do you use application insight ?

Comment: Same here, I've not changed nothing

Comment: I'm using the latest: 2.9.

Answer (score 2):

I got a different answer from MS support: “Our Product Team has rolled back the changes.”

I test it, and now I can publish with the diagnostic enabled without problem.

Comment: Interesting timing.  It seems to be working now (7 AM EST  2/7/2017).

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer from the support : it's an identified backend issue and the tech team is working on it with the highest priority.

As a workaround, disable diagnostics :

[image]